# Is it possible to define the operator similar to the Displacement $|\alpha\rangle = \hat D|0\rangle$ but from the coherent state to the Fock space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, coherent-states

I am looking for the theory of electro-optical modulator with Fock states as an input and I know how the modulator acts on the coherent states. Knowing the connection between coherent and Fock states. Is it possible to define the operator similar to the Displacement $$|\alpha\rangle = \hat D|0\rangle$$ but from $$|\alpha\rangle\to|n\rangle$$?

Comment: Something like projection  $X_n =|n\rangle\langle n|$?

Comment: What does "similar to" mean?! There's *lots* of operators of that type. E.g. $(\hat n)^n {\hat D}^{-1}$ will do.

Comment: $$D^{-1}$$is just $$D(-\alpha)$$, so it is not the same. Similar means that I act on Fock state by an operator (hopefully unitary) and get a coherent state

Comment: Sorry, typo. I meant $(a^\dagger)^n D^{-1}$, of course. $D^{-1}$ will give |0>, from which $(a^\dagger)^n$ will create |n>. -- P.S.: You need to tag me with @[name] if you want that I get notified of your comment. (Conversely it is not necessary since I am commenting below your post.)

Comment: Note that such a unitary *always* exists: Any state can be mapped to any other state by a unitary. Things might be different if you impose contraints on the unitary.